# Git extract commits as separate files

Tags: git, version-control

I have a git repo with one file which has new commits added almost daily.

I would like to extract copies of the file as it looked at every commit to a new directory.

Ideally the files would be date-stamped (`2017_08_24.txt`) according to when the commit was made.

I've already tried `git format-patch -o directory --root HEAD` but this exports the changelog, not the full file as it looked at the time of the commit.

Thanks

Comment: I’m going to close this as a duplicate since there are enough questions covering how to get a file version from a specific revision. The task to create a script to retrieve and save *all* versions of a file is left to the OP (remember this is not a code-writing service). Combined with `git log` (which can be called to just show commit ids), this shouldn’t be too difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git show <commit>:<file>` will gove you the contents of a file as it was in a specific commit hash. You could use `git log` to get all the commits on a file, and then use `xargs` to pass them on to `git show`.

The following command line will extract a series of files with the original name and the commit hash concatinated to them:

```
$ git log --format="%H" /path/to/file | \
xargs -I % sh -c "git show %:/path/to/file > /path/to/target/filename.%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bash script. It's not fully tested. You can modify it as you like.

```
#!/bin/bash

branch=$1
file=$2

git log --pretty=%H $branch | while read hash;do 
    object="$branch:$file"
    objecthash=$(git rev-parse $object 2>/dev/null)
    if [ "$object" != "$objecthash" ];then
        git cat-file -p $objecthash > $(git log -1 --pretty=%cd --date=format:%Y%m%d_%H%M%S $hash).txt
    else 
        echo "$file does not exist in $hash"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For a specific commit you can retrieve the file version like this

```
git show 23uggf2f8g:myfile.txt > backupDir/oldVersion.txt
```

But I think that you have to write a script to do that automatically for every commit